# Determining whether an ideal is prime in $\Bbb Q[X,Y,Z,W]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Is the ideal $(XZ^2-W^3, XW^2-Y^4, Y^4Z^2-W^5)$ prime in $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y,Z,W]$?

I tried writing the ideal as the kernel of a parametrization of the form $f(X) = T^a$, $f(Y) = T^b$, $f(Z) = T^c$ and $f(W)=T^d$ but it seems to be quite important how to choose $a,b,c,d$ in order to actually prove that the ideal is the kernel of such a homomorphism and most of the things I tried do not work.

I also got a hint that one of the generators can be written in terms of the other two, but I do not see how this helps. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Look at $\mathbb{A}^2\to\mathbb{A}^4$ given by $(x,y)\mapsto(x^{12},x^5y,y^3,x^4y^2)$?

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$Y^4Z^2-W^5=W^2(XZ^2-W^3)-W^2XZ^2+Y^4Z^2=W^2(XZ^2-W^3)+Z^2(Y^4-XW^2).$$

So the ideal $I=(XZ^2-W^3, Y^4-XW^2)$.

Comment: Your claim is false. For instance, $X - Z$ and  $X - W$ are in $\ker(f)$, but neither is in $I$. In fact, $\ker(f) = \left(Z - W, X - W, Y^{4} - W^{3}\right)$.

Comment: You are right. Silly me!